# Passing parameters to plugin constructor via MEF on .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, mef

I spent several hours trying to figure out how to pass parameters to a plugin constructor via MEF (System.Composition) but all to no avail.  Needless to say, there are very few relevant docs and a look through the source code didn't help.

This used to be really easy to do, using the CompositionHost.ComposeExportedValue method, but in the .NET Core version I can't seem to find anything that works.  I've enclosed my incomplete code, below, followed by the exception that is thrown.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks....

```
using System;
using System.Composition;
using System.Composition.Hosting;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MefMe
{
    public interface IPlugin
    {
        void Alert();
    }

    [Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
    public class Plugin : IPlugin
    {
        private string code;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public Plugin(string code)
        {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public void Alert() => Console.WriteLine(code);
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ContainerConfiguration()
                .WithAssembly(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

            var container = config.CreateContainer();

            // Throws a CompositionFailedException; see notes
            var plugin = container.GetExport<IPlugin>();

            plugin.Alert();
        }
    }
}
```

> System.Composition.Hosting.CompositionFailedException occurred
>   HResult=0x80131500   Message=No export was found for the contract
>   'String'  -> required by import 'code' of part 'Plugin'  -> required
>   by initial request for contract 'IPlugin'   Source=   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Composition.Hosting.Core.ExportDescriptorRegistryUpdate.CheckTarget(CompositionDependency
>   dependency, HashSet`1 checked, Stack`1 checking)    at
>   System.Composition.Hosting.Core.ExportDescriptorRegistryUpdate.CheckDependency(CompositionDependency
>   dependency, HashSet`1 checked, Stack`1 checking)    at
>   System.Composition.Hosting.Core.ExportDescriptorRegistryUpdate.CheckTarget(CompositionDependency
>   dependency, HashSet`1 checked, Stack`1 checking)    at
>   System.Composition.Hosting.Core.ExportDescriptorRegistryUpdate.Execute(CompositionContract
>   contract)    at
>   System.Composition.Hosting.Core.ExportDescriptorRegistry.TryGetSingleForExport(CompositionContract
>   exportKey, ExportDescriptor& defaultForExport)    at
>   System.Composition.Hosting.Core.LifetimeContext.TryGetExport(CompositionContract
>   contract, Object& export)    at
>   System.Composition.CompositionContext.GetExport(CompositionContract
>   contract)    at
>   System.Composition.CompositionContext.GetExport[TExport](String
>   contractName)    at MefMe.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\louis\Desktop\MefMe\MefMe\Program.cs:line 36

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `ComposeExportedValue` is not currently supported. There is an open [Github Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11856) requesting the feature.

There is a long winded workaround that will do the trick. There is no way that I can find to create exports on the fly with populated values. What you can do is create explicit property exports with the values set in the constructor via a static bag of parameters. I have updated your code snippet to show my solution.

```
 namespace MefMe
{
    public interface IPlugin
    {
        void Alert();
    }

    [Export( typeof( IPlugin ) )]
    public class Plugin : IPlugin
    {
        private string code;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public Plugin( [Import( "code" )] object code )
        {
            this.code = (string)code;
        }

        public void Alert() => Console.WriteLine( code );
    }

    public class Parameters
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, object>> PopulatedParameters { get; set; }
        [Export( "code", typeof( object ) )]
        public object code { get; set; }

        public Parameters()
        {
            foreach (var param in PopulatedParameters)
                SetParameter( param.Item1, param.Item2 );
        }

        void SetParameter( string nameOfParam, object value )
        {
            var property = typeof( Parameters ).GetProperty( nameOfParam, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance );
            property.SetValue( this, value );
        }


    }

    public class Program
    {           
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            Parameters.PopulatedParameters = new Tuple<string, object>[] { new Tuple<string, object>( "code", "myvalue" ) };

            var config = new ContainerConfiguration()
                .WithAssembly( typeof( IPlugin ).Assembly );
            var container = config.CreateContainer();

            // Throws a CompositionFailedException; see notes
            var plugin = container.GetExport<IPlugin>();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For now you need to build your own ExportDescriptorProvider.  Then add it into the container config using "WithProvider".  Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321270/compose-exported-value-with-mef-2).

(That one was almost exactly the same question.)

Don't mean to take credit for anyone else's work; I just think stackoverflow can use a LOT more material related to System.Composition.